# Can't uninstall the software

Tags: software-uninstall

Tried to remove the software from Ubuntu software center but in search the is coming up again and the app is working. how to uninstall the app?

Comment: You haven't told us what app.  Myself I use terminal, and the command varies on what & how it was installed (eg. you could have installed snaps & deb formatted software from Ubuntu software).  For a snap it's `sudo snap remove <snappackage>` and for a deb it's `sudo apt remove <package>`.  In the Software Centre you should have a 'remove' option (but you didn't tell us your release of Ubuntu so I can't be specific).

Comment: An advantage to using terminal is the messages (if there are problems/issues) appear on your screen.  With the software-centre you need to scan logs for those messages, which isn't difficult but an extra step.  Thus you could check your logs, or use terminal & read the error messages off your screen.

Comment: How you uninstall software depends entirely upon how you originally installed it.

Answer (score 1):

- For packages installed using APT:

  ```
  sudo apt-get purge <package-name>
  ```
- For snap packages:

  ```
  sudo snap remove <package-name>
  ```